# Is it safe to use CURRENCY_SYMBOL as a define in PHP?

Tags: php

We currently use CURRENCY_SYMBOL as a defined constant in PHP 7.  A build of the latest Zend engine chokes on this as a re-definition and it is clear from the source code that a symbol of this name is being defined by PHP.  However, an installation of PHP 8 has no problem and the symbol is initially undefined.
What is the reason for the disparity?  Would it be best to change the name of this define to avoid future issues or is this unnecessary?

Comment: Either this is a defined constant anywhere else, or it is not. What's the difference between that "latest Zend engine" and a current installation of PHP 8?